# What do I do to use this pyportmidi (pypm) as a library in python?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, midi, pypm

This is apparently the source code here (though I'm not sure):

https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/01b2cb16dc17/src/pypm.pyx

I'm new to programming and trying to use python as an audio engine.  This seemed like pretty much the only way to send midi messages from python.

I really have no idea what to do with the information provided at the link.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame can send midi messages: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html
And a demo in the examples folder: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/examples.html#pygame.examples.midi.main

I believe you linked the source code of pygame itself, and not a demo.